# How does lower network bandwidth and lower latency create a bottleneck for POS Blockchain network?

Tags: proof-of-stake

My understanding is that any proof of stake blockchain would largely remove the processing power and energy consumption bottleneck from the whole system, but even after that the blockchain nodes should still face the problem of lower bandwidth, lower latency from the physical network. 
I want to know what percentage of time out of the total transaction completion time is spent on the wire communication between nodes. If say the bandwidth of the system increases 5 fold, and latency of communication between nodes reduces 5 fold, what sort of effect there might be on the POS blockchain network latency and throughput? Can anybody suggest any solid paper that will provide me a function to calculate this?